# Summing and rounding fractions multiplied by number to equal number?

Tags: javascript, rounding, fractions

In JavaScript, 
Given (x) number of fractions like this:

```
0.3
0.3
0.2
0.1
0.1
```

(That sum to 1)

How can I make sure that when I multiply these by a number (n), say 1000, and round the results to integers, the sum of these integers will equal (n)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Largest Remainder Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_remainder_method):

**Step 1:** Multiply the numbers by `n` (in this case, let's use an `n` that doesn't immediately work out so nicely to demonstrate that the LRM still works; I choose 737), and separate the whole and fractional parts.

```
0.3 * 737 = 221 + 0.1
0.3 * 737 = 221 + 0.1
0.2 * 737 = 147 + 0.4
0.1 * 737 = 73 + 0.7
0.1 * 737 = 73 + 0.7
```

**Step 2:** Sum up the whole number parts

```
221 + 221 + 147 + 73 + 73 = 735
```

**Step 3:** Sort the remainders from highest to lowest

```
High to low: 0.7, 0.7, 0.4, 0.1, 0.1
```

**Step 4:** Add `1` to the whole number components with the associated largest remainders until the sum equals `n`.

In our case, we are 2 away from the target sum (`737`), and `0.7` is the largest remainder, which occurs twice. `0.7` is associated with `0.1`, so add 1 to `0.1`'s whole number.

Your final list is:

```
221
221
147
74
74
```

Comment: Great answer and thanks for 1) Linking to the actual method so that I remember the term and 2) for giving the solution stepwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can't guarantee it if you multiply, round, and sum.  Why don't you sum first, then multiply, then round?